# Lync 2013 voice - is it possible to have incoming calls have Caller ID from a personal contact?

Tags: lync

This is one of those where I'm not sure where to look.

I found this TechNet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351203(v=exchg.141).aspx - but it appears to only be for when UM kicks in for a missed call or for voicemail.

I'm curious if there's a way to have Lync voice match a personal contact when receiving an incoming call.  This way our users will know who is calling without having to remember the external number.  I'm referring to calls from outside the organization.

I tried testing this internally by creating a few personal contacts in my Outlook with the exact phone number syntax that Lync uses such as +1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx.  However, this didn't change anything.  Incoming calls still just show the number.  However, if I miss the call and get a voicemail the UM message will show the contact in that voicemail email.

Before I run to Microsoft, I thought I'd check here and see if anyone has some suggestions or links to something that might work.

Comment: This should work out of the box. 
Can you try the number in the contact without the brackets, spaces and dashes?

Also is Outlook integration working? The best way to test this is do a search in the Lync client for one of the Outlook contacts you have created.